# android recyclerview not showing anything

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview, adapter

I'm using RecyclerView with a custom Adapter but it's not showing data.

Code of adapter.class

```
public class AdapterList extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterList.ViewHolder> {
    Context context;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list_data;

    public AdapterList(Appetizer1 appetizer1, ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list_data){
        this.context = appetizer1;
        this.list_data = list_data;
    }


    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_iitem,null);

        return new ViewHolder(view) ;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(AdapterList.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Glide.with(context).load("http://kelompokdua.hol.es/pic/" + list_data.get(position)
        .get("gambar")).crossFade().placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .into(holder.imgfood);
        holder.txtfood.setText(list_data.get(position).get("nama"));
        holder.txtid.setText(list_data.get(position).get("id"));
        holder.txtharga.setText(list_data.get(position).get("harga"));

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list_data.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView txtfood,txtid,txtharga;
        ImageView imgfood;

        public ViewHolder (View itemView){
            super(itemView);

            txtfood = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_nama);
            txtid = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_id);
            txtharga = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_harga);
            imgfood = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);

        }
    }
}
```

code of mainactivity.class

```
public class Appetizer1 extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView lvfood;
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;
    private StringRequest stringRequest;

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list_data;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_appetizer1);

        String url = "http://kelompokdua.hol.es/private_html/show.php";
        lvfood = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv1);
        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        lvfood.setLayoutManager(llm);

        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Appetizer1.this);
        list_data = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d("response", response);
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("");
                    for (int a = 0; a < jsonArray.length(); a++) {
                        JSONObject json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(a);
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        map.put("id", String.valueOf(json.getInt("id")));
                        map.put("nama", json.getString("nama"));
                        map.put("harga", String.valueOf(json.getInt("harga")));
                        map.put("gambar", json.getString("gambar"));
                        list_data.add(map);
                        AdapterList adapter = new AdapterList(Appetizer1.this, list_data);
                        lvfood.setAdapter(adapter);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(Appetizer1.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

    }}
```

and this is my json result:

```
[[{"id":"1","nama":"Martabak","harga":"25000","gambar":"http:\/\/kelompokdua.hol.es\/pic\/martabak.jpg"},{"id":"2","nama":"Ayam Goreng","harga":"20000","gambar":"http:\/\/kelompokdua.hol.es\/pic\/ayam.jpg"},{"id":"3","nama":"Nasi Goreng","harga":"15000","gambar":"http:\/\/kelompokdua.hol.es\/pic\/nasigor.jpg"},{"id":"4","nama":"Cola","harga":"5000","gambar":"http:\/\/kelompokdua.hol.es\/pic\/cocacola.jpg"},{"id":"5","nama":"Es teh manis","harga":"3000","gambar":"http:\/\/kelompokdua.hol.es\/pic\/esteh.jpg"},{"id":"6","nama":"Jus","harga":"18000","gambar":"http:\/\/kelompokdua.hol.es\/pic\/juice.jpg"},{"id":"7","nama":"Pasta","harga":"20000","gambar":"http:\/\/kelompokdua.hol.es\/pic\/pasta.jpg"}]]
```

this is my adapterlist.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/cardView">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="167dp"
                app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_id"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_nama"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_harga"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and this mainactivity.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.kelompok3.restaurantapp.restoranfixx.Isimenu.Appetizer1">

        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.kelompok3.restaurantapp.restoranfixx.Isimenu.Appetizer1">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv1"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="495dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

i don't see any error on the logcat, i'm so confused. it just show a blank layout. i've changed the visibility but nothing happened. After i tried any suggestion now the problem is

```
E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
```

Comment: Setting new Adapter instances on the same Listview inside of a for loop seems odd. I think you meant to create and set the adapter after the for loop.

Comment: Post activity layout and row item layout

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks perfect. Just check that your Recyclerview is visible in XML file. May be by mistake you made the visibility gone or anything. Just check that and let me know or you can just check it by doing below code

```
AdapterList adapter = new AdapterList(Appetizer1.this, list_data);
lvfood.setAdapter(adapter);
lvfood.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Show the visibility of recyclerview like this:-

```
lvfood.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
lvfood.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Move following line out of the for loop

```
AdapterList adapter = new AdapterList(Appetizer1.this, list_data);
lvfood.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Also please make sure list is visible in xml.

```
lvfood.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: i move it, but nothing changed. i also set the visible too

Comment: Your xml has error, please update your question with correct layout

Comment: have a look sir, i changed it. my mistakes

Answer (score 0):

I would try to move this two lines:

```
AdapterList adapter = new AdapterList(Appetizer1.this, list_data);
lvfood.setAdapter(adapter);
```

You should move them out from the for loop, otherwise you create and set a new Adapter for every JSONObject in that array.
I would also suggest to create a class that contains the JSONObject's attributes, so you can use a List instead of a HashMap.

Also, as someone else suggested, try to check the RecyclerView Visibility:

```
lvfood.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: so i have to move it out a braces?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in your link in `Glide`. You are storing full link from JSON. But when you trying to load that image you also add header link that's why image not loading.
Just change the `Gilde` link like that.
`Glide.with(context).load(list_data.get(position).get("gambar")).crossFade().placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).into(holder.imgfood);`

Comment: it say illegal line end in string literall

Comment: it's stay blank sir

Comment: In your Adapter Class
`imgfood = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);`
`R.id.thumbnail` should change to `R.id.ivFood`

Comment: i changed my xml sir, my mistakes. have a look

Answer (score 0):

Replace this code onResponse() method

```
 try {              

                JSONArray response1=new JSONArray(response);
                JSONArray jsonArray = response1.getJSONArray(0);
                for (int a = 0; a < jsonArray.length(); a++) {
                    JSONObject json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(a);
                    try {
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();


                        map.put("id", String.valueOf(json.getInt("id")));
                        map.put("nama", json.getString("nama"));
                        map.put("harga", String.valueOf(json.getInt("harga")));
                        map.put("gambar", json.getString("gambar"));
                        list_data.add(map);

                    } catch (JSONException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }


                }
                AdapterList adapter = new AdapterList(getApplicationContext(), list_data);
                lvfood.setAdapter(adapter);
            }catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

And declare in Arraylist like that

```
 ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list_data=new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: i got this issue sir, cannot resolve method getJSONArray and adapterlist cannot be applied to arraylist

Comment: @Fawwaz Ok Then add this code above this code JSONArray response1=new JSONArray(response); Then call response1.getJSONArray(0);

Comment: the logcat said E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Comment: View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item,parent,false);
replace this code in AdapterClass in viewHolder method add viewGroup and false